# Where to find all available __attribute__ options

Tags: c++, gcc

I am currently wokring with AVX/SSE library and want to make a runtime decision procedure for evaluating which instructions are available on given architecture and OS and use appropriate overloaded function. In that library, there is already a mechanism for that, but is flawed.

I am not going in a complete detail here, but the mentioned mechanism uses the __attribute__ (__target__()) syntax, which allows compilation of a function it is put before with different flags than the rest of the program. However, trying to find out how to correctly use that to compile SIMD-instruction based functions proved to be quite difficult, mainly because on official manual (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html#x86-Function-Attributes) the list of options for __attribute__ (__target__()) is incomplete. At the very least, options 'avx' and 'avx2' is missing.

In fact, comparing the content in here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html#x86-Function-Attributes and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html does not seem to be that much different.

So my question is, where can I find a complete list and other important related information to __attribute__ (__target__()) options available with gcc-v7.2.0 x86-64 compiler?

Comment: The names sited in this function attribute documentation are all matched by the name of instructions that can be enabled at the command line: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options. So there is a chance that all those options are also valid target attributes.

Comment: Also in the documentation related to cpuid, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html#x86-Built-in-Functions, the function called "__builtin_cpu_support" which is used by target resolver also sites avx2,avx512f.

Comment: I did read both, but though it is true they are related, they are not corresponding. The cpu_built_in allows to ask on avx instruction availability, but is independent of the arguments for \_\_attribute\_\_ (\_\_target\_\_()), it is just that those two overlap to some level in capabilities. And with the compiler options, the description of attribute(target()) says, that those options are equivalent to this or that flag. But they are not all available as options for attribute(target()), and the ones that are, only have a corresponding value, it is not available with the same name/value.

Comment: At least as far as I can tell...

Answer (score 0):

The real issue here is that the documentation has lagged behind the implementation - this is, unfortunately something that happens, and when it does happen, the only real solution is to defer to the source to determine what's available, or ask the compiler directly.

Firstly, you're asking about `__attribute__(__target__())`. This effectively changes the compilation options for what's attributed to match the target specified, so if you pass in `avx2`, it'll be built with that extension.

The full list of extensions for any version of gcc can be extracted from the help output of gcc; so, for example with the docker container `gcc:7.2.0`, I can do the following:

```
$ docker run --rm  gcc:7.2.0 gcc -v --help 2>&1 | awk '/^[ ]+-march=C/ { P=1; } /^[ ]+-mtune=C/ { P=0; } P==1 { print; }'
  -march=CPU[,+EXTENSION...]
                      generate code for CPU and EXTENSION, CPU is one of:
                       generic32, generic64, i386, i486, i586, i686,
                       pentium, pentiumpro, pentiumii, pentiumiii, pentium4,
                       prescott, nocona, core, core2, corei7, l1om, k1om,
                       iamcu, k6, k6_2, athlon, opteron, k8, amdfam10,
                       bdver1, bdver2, bdver3, bdver4, znver1, btver1,
                       btver2
                      EXTENSION is combination of:
                       8087, 287, 387, 687, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3,
                       sse4.1, sse4.2, sse4, avx, avx2, avx512f, avx512cd,
                       avx512er, avx512pf, avx512dq, avx512bw, avx512vl,
                       vmx, vmfunc, smx, xsave, xsaveopt, xsavec, xsaves,
                       aes, pclmul, fsgsbase, rdrnd, f16c, bmi2, fma, fma4,
                       xop, lwp, movbe, cx16, ept, lzcnt, hle, rtm, invpcid,
                       clflush, nop, syscall, rdtscp, 3dnow, 3dnowa,
                       padlock, svme, sse4a, abm, bmi, tbm, adx, rdseed,
                       prfchw, smap, mpx, sha, clflushopt, prefetchwt1, se1,
                       clwb, avx512ifma, avx512vbmi, avx512_4fmaps,
                       avx512_4vnniw, avx512_vpopcntdq, clzero, mwaitx,
                       ospke, rdpid, ptwrite, no87, no287, no387, no687,
                       nommx, nosse, nosse2, nosse3, nossse3, nosse4.1,
                       nosse4.2, nosse4, noavx, noavx2, noavx512f,
                       noavx512cd, noavx512er, noavx512pf, noavx512dq,
                       noavx512bw, noavx512vl, noavx512ifma, noavx512vbmi,
                       noavx512_4fmaps, noavx512_4vnniw, noavx512_vpopcntdq
```

So based on this data, there are quite a few target attributes you can add for 7.2.0

And then for gcc 13.1.0:

```
$ docker run --rm  gcc:13.1.0 gcc -v --help 2>&1 | awk '/^[ ]+-march=C/ { P=1; } /^[ ]+-mtune=C/ { P=0; } P==1 { print; }'
  -march=CPU[,+EXTENSION...]
                      generate code for CPU and EXTENSION, CPU is one of:
                       default, push, pop, generic32, generic64, i386, i486,
                       i586, i686, pentium, pentiumpro, pentiumii,
                       pentiumiii, pentium4, prescott, nocona, core, core2,
                       corei7, iamcu, k6, k6_2, athlon, opteron, k8,
                       amdfam10, bdver1, bdver2, bdver3, bdver4, znver1,
                       znver2, znver3, znver4, btver1, btver2
                      EXTENSION is combination of (possibly "no"-prefixed):
                       8087, 287, 387, 687, cmov, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2,
                       sse3, sse4a, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, sse4, avx, avx2,
                       avx512f, avx512cd, avx512er, avx512pf, avx512dq,
                       avx512bw, avx512vl, vmx, vmfunc, smx, xsave,
                       xsaveopt, xsavec, xsaves, aes, pclmul, fsgsbase,
                       rdrnd, f16c, bmi2, fma, fma4, xop, lwp, movbe, cx16,
                       ept, lzcnt, popcnt, hle, rtm, tsx, invpcid, clflush,
                       nop, syscall, rdtscp, 3dnow, 3dnowa, padlock, svme,
                       abm, bmi, tbm, adx, rdseed, prfchw, smap, mpx, sha,
                       clflushopt, prefetchwt1, se1, clwb, avx512ifma,
                       avx512vbmi, avx512_4fmaps, avx512_4vnniw,
                       avx512_vpopcntdq, avx512_vbmi2, avx512_vnni,
                       avx512_bitalg, avx_vnni, clzero, mwaitx, ospke,
                       rdpid, ptwrite, ibt, shstk, gfni, vaes, vpclmulqdq,
                       wbnoinvd, pconfig, waitpkg, cldemote, amx_int8,
                       amx_bf16, amx_fp16, amx_tile, movdiri, movdir64b,
                       avx512_bf16, avx512_vp2intersect, tdx, enqcmd,
                       serialize, rdpru, mcommit, sev_es, tsxldtrk, kl,
                       widekl, uintr, hreset, avx512_fp16, prefetchi,
                       avx_ifma, avx_vnni_int8, cmpccxadd, wrmsrns, msrlist,
                       avx_ne_convert, rao_int, rmpquery, no87
```

And then for gcc 4.9.4:

```
$ docker run --rm  gcc:4.9.4 gcc -v --help 2>&1 | awk '/^[ ]+-march=C/ { P=1; } /^[ ]+-mtune=C/ { P=0; } P==1 { print; }'
  -march=CPU[,+EXTENSION...]
                      generate code for CPU and EXTENSION, CPU is one of:
                       generic32, generic64, i386, i486, i586, i686,
                       pentium, pentiumpro, pentiumii, pentiumiii, pentium4,
                       prescott, nocona, core, core2, corei7, l1om, k1om,
                       k6, k6_2, athlon, opteron, k8, amdfam10, bdver1,
                       bdver2, bdver3, bdver4, btver1, btver2
                      EXTENSION is combination of:
                       8087, 287, 387, no87, mmx, nommx, sse, sse2, sse3,
                       ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, sse4, nosse, avx, avx2,
                       avx512f, avx512cd, avx512er, avx512pf, avx512dq,
                       avx512bw, avx512vl, noavx, vmx, vmfunc, smx, xsave,
                       xsaveopt, xsavec, xsaves, aes, pclmul, fsgsbase,
                       rdrnd, f16c, bmi2, fma, fma4, xop, lwp, movbe, cx16,
                       ept, lzcnt, hle, rtm, invpcid, clflush, nop, syscall,
                       rdtscp, 3dnow, 3dnowa, padlock, svme, sse4a, abm,
                       bmi, tbm, adx, rdseed, prfchw, smap, mpx, sha,
                       clflushopt, prefetchwt1, se1, clwb, pcommit,
                       avx512ifma, avx512vbmi
```

So you can use this to determine the full list of available options for compilation.

Note, however, that there are bugs - sometimes what you ask for doesn't happen, but that's rare for most of the compilation options.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it, but seems to be the desired answer.